# Event target incorrectly set as font element instead of p element

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I've got a backbone app with an event handler similar to that below which is bound to a p element:

```
onClickFilter: function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.outerHTML);  // element sometimes reported as font instead of p
}
```

Because the app logs errors to a server, I've seen that some users have encountered a javascript error resulting from this event target being a font element (there are not even any font elements in the code).  This problem has occurred on a few different places in the app.  Unfortunately, I have been unable to reproduce the issue on various browsers/devices.  Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: In some old browsers, the event target was the originating node so it might be a text node. You can try something like: `var tgt = event.target; if (tgt.nodeType != 1) tgt = tgt.parentNode;` but that is just a guess.

Comment: I do get the user agent info for the reports of this and it occurs on new browsers (latest Chrome versions on win and mac).  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`event.target` is the *originating* element, which can be a descendant element of the element on which you bound the event, because most events (including `click`) bubble from the originating element to its ancestors. If you want the element on which you bound the event, with modern mechanisms it's `this` or `event.currentTarget`. If you're dealing with IE and `attachEvent`, you have to handle it yourself with closures.

But for example:

```
<div id="target"><span>Click me</span></div>
```

And

```
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
});
```

Clicks on the words "click me" will log `SPAN`, not `DIV`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain why the issue only occurs for some users (and can't be repro'd locally).  (unfortunately, I haven't been able to contact a user to repro either)

Comment: @user3348881: Perhaps they have some browser extension (or branded browser) that does something like add wrapper elements around certain text on the page.

Comment: I've wondered about that as well, but I'm not sure where to start tracking this down (other than this post).  Thanks for your suggestions that might be worth doing anyway.